# Laravel Socialite - Different Providers With Same Email - Security How to Fix

Tags: laravel, laravel-socialite

Ok so I read how to implement Laravel socialite into my application so I can let users log in using Google or Facebook. I read how to do it [here](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/using-github-authentication-for-login-with-laravel-socialite). The problem I encounter with this approach is that if a user logs in from say Google with email myemail@example.com then logs in from Facebook using myemail@example.com they are logging into the same account! Security issue right. So I thought that before I let them log in I would check the provider id which you can get, however when I try to compare the provider_id that I store in the database when they create the account with the provider_id stored in the socialite user variable I get this error:

Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse given

Here is all the code I am using for Socialite:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Socialite;
use App\User;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Flash;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;

class SocialiteController extends Controller
{

    public function redirectToProvider($provider)
    {
        return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect();
    }

    public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
    {
        try
        {
            $social_user = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
             return Redirect::to('auth/' . $provider);
        }
        $authUser = $this->findOrCreateUser($social_user);
        Auth::login($authUser, true);
        flash()->overlay('You have been logged in successfully!', 'Congratulations');
        return Redirect::to('/');

    }
    //create a new user in our database or grab existing user
    private function findOrCreateUser($social_user)
    {
        if ($authUser = User::where('email', $social_user->email)->first()) {
            //this creates an error
            if($authUser->provider_id == $social_user->id)
                return $authUser;
            else
            {
                flash()->overlay('An account for that email already exists!', 'Error');
                return Redirect::to('/');
            }
        }


        return User::Create([
            'provider_id' => $social_user->id,
            'name' => $social_user->name,
            'email' => $social_user->email,
            'nickname' => $social_user->nickname,
            'avatar_img' => $social_user->avatar,
            'role_id' => 1, //set role to guest
            'social_login' => true //tell the database they are logging in from oauth

        ]);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is actually self explained. 
When you do `User::where('provider_id', $social_user->id)` you end up with builder object that implements

`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`.

You can call `->get()` on it to get the collection of results 
(a collection of objects that implements

`Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable`

in your case, so you can iterate over them), or as you did, you can get the first match with `->first()` (one object that implement

`Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable`).

You can read more in the Eloquent documentation.

The main point is that until you call `->get()` or `->first()` you are working with builder object. 
There is actually `->find()` method also, that is used to retrieve record by pk, you cannot use it to search for records by constraints (`where`), but it also returns model object.

Comment: This answer was originally posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37247380/laravel-socialite-user-getid

Answer (score 0):

> The problem I encounter with this approach is that if a user logs in
>   from say Google with email myemail@example.com then logs in from
>   Facebook using myemail@example.com they are logging into the same
>   account! Security issue right.

In my opinion, this is an incorrect assumption. It is not a security issue.

OAuth is used as an authentication delegation, if a user controls accounts in different providers with the same email, it simply means he has more 3rd party OAuth services with which to validate control of his identity (email)

I would consider it a bug, if you limited me to only be able to sign in with one OAuth provider, and prohibited me to user another one with the same email.