# Laravel socialite $user->getId()?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

I'm not sure if this is what is really causing my issue, but perhaps someone will know. When I use Laravel Socialite and go:

```
$social_user = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();
```

Then somewhere else in my code is do this:

```
if ($authUser = User::where('provider_id', $social_user->id)) 
        return $authUser;
```

For some crazy reason I get an error like this:

Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder given

However if I do this I don't get an error:

```
if($authUser = User::where('email', $social_user->email)->first())
        return $authUser;
```

I log this user in like this:

```
Auth::login($authUser, true);
```

Does anyone know why? I'm using laravel 5.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is actually self explained. When you do `User::where('provider_id', $social_user->id)` you end up with **builder object** that implements `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`. You can call `->get()` on it to get the **collection of results** (a collection of objects that implements `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable` in your case, so you can iterate over them), or as you did, you can get the **first match** with `->first()` (one object that implement `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable`). You can read more in the [Eloquent documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent).

The main point is that **until you call** `->get()` or `->first()` you are working with **builder object**. There is actually `->find()` method also, that is used to retrieve record by `pk`, you cannot use it to search for records by constraints (where), but it also returns model object.